# Avoid function in where clause,due to that its causing performance issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Whenever I'm executing the procedure I got performance issue, where do I need to change the procedure to increase the performance?

I have called table function in where clause I need to optimize this procedure without using string.

```sql
CREATE PROC proc_productwise_report @cmp_id VARCHAR(max), @unitcode VARCHAR(max), @gr_code VARCHAR(max), @store_code VARCHAR(max), @from_dt VARCHAR(20), @to_dt VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT sh.cmp_id, d.unitcode, d.store_code, st.item_code AS product, d.item_code, im.item_desc, SUM(charge_qty) AS challan_qty
    FROM ps_invenstatic sh
    INNER JOIN ps_invenstaticdet st ON sh.cmp_id = st.cmp_id
        AND sh.sys_no_id = st.sys_no_id
        AND sh.doc_id = st.doc_id
        AND sys_doc_type = 'PSCH'
    INNER JOIN ps_invenissu h ON sh.cmp_id = h.cmp_id
        AND sh.doc_type = h.ref_doc_type
        AND sh.doc_no = h.ref_doc_no
        AND h.prod_code = st.item_code
    INNER JOIN ps_invenissudet d ON h.cmp_id = d.cmp_id
        AND h.sys_no_id = d.sys_no_id
        AND h.doc_id = d.doc_id
    INNER JOIN ps_itemmas im ON sh.cmp_id = im.cmp_id
        AND im.item_code = d.item_code
    WHERE sh.cmp_id IN (
            SELECT *
            FROM utilfn_split(@cmp_id, ',')
            )
        AND d.unitcode IN (
            SELECT *
            FROM utilfn_split(@unitcode, ',')
            )
        AND im.gr_code IN (
            SELECT *
            FROM utilfn_split(@gr_code, ',')
            )
        AND d.store_code IN (
            SELECT *
            FROM utilfn_split(@store_code, ',')
            )
        AND h.doc_dt BETWEEN convert(DATETIME, @from_dt, 103)
            AND convert(DATETIME, @to_dt, 103)
        AND sh.Stat_Code <> 'CA'
    GROUP BY sh.cmp_id, d.unitcode, d.store_code, st.item_code, d.item_code, im.item_desc
END
```

I need to avoid function in where clause and resolve the performance issue.

Comment: Save results of `utilfn_split` to table variables and `INNER JOIN` to them.

Comment: @Alex , using `INNER JOIN` has a prerequisite all values in the parameter are unique. This is most likely scenario but  `IN` or `EXISTS` would be a safer option.

Comment: @Serg, `DISTINCT` when inserting into table variable will solve uniqueness problems. `IN` has a tendency to produce bad query plans, when it is expanded to a bunch of `OR` statements.

Comment: @Alex - `IN` from a table source (as opposed to a comma delimited values list) is never "expanded to a bunch of OR statements." - it always gives a semi join - same as `EXISTS`

Comment: @MartinSmith, I stand corrected then.

Comment: ...Your `GROUP BY` is pretty wide.  At minimum, I suspect at least the join to `ps_itemmas` can be performed against a subquery that does the summation, and possibly additional tables as well.  You absolutely should not [use `BETWEEN` with `DATETIME`, however](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (although this should not affect your performance, it will affect correctness).

Comment: you should supply the actual execution plan as XML so we can see where the specific problems are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build temporary tables in your stored procedure with the result of the SPLIT and INNER JOIN those temporary tables in your main query.

```
CREATE PROC proc_productwise_report @cmp_id VARCHAR(max), @unitcode VARCHAR(max), 
@gr_code VARCHAR(max), @store_code VARCHAR(max), @from_dt VARCHAR(20), @to_dt VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT *
INTO #cmp_ids
FROM utilfn_split(@cmp_id, ',');

SELECT *
INTO #unitcodes
FROM utilfn_split(@unitcode, ',');

SELECT *
INTO #gr_codes
FROM utilfn_split(@gr_code, ',');

SELECT *
INTO #store_codes
FROM utilfn_split(@store_code, ',');

SELECT 
    sh.cmp_id
    , d.unitcode
    , d.store_code
    , st.item_code AS product
    , d.item_code
    , im.item_desc
    , SUM(charge_qty) AS challan_qty
FROM ps_invenstatic sh
    INNER JOIN ps_invenstaticdet st 
        ON sh.cmp_id = st.cmp_id
            AND sh.sys_no_id = st.sys_no_id
            AND sh.doc_id = st.doc_id
            AND sys_doc_type = 'PSCH'
    INNER JOIN ps_invenissu h 
        ON sh.cmp_id = h.cmp_id
            AND sh.doc_type = h.ref_doc_type
            AND sh.doc_no = h.ref_doc_no
            AND h.prod_code = st.item_code
    INNER JOIN ps_invenissudet d 
        ON h.cmp_id = d.cmp_id
            AND h.sys_no_id = d.sys_no_id
            AND h.doc_id = d.doc_id
    INNER JOIN ps_itemmas im 
        ON sh.cmp_id = im.cmp_id
            AND im.item_code = d.item_code
    INNER JOIN #cmp_ids tci on sh.cmp_id = tci.[value]
    INNER JOIN #unitcodes tuc on d.unitcode = tuc.[value]
    INNER JOIN #gr_codes tgr on im.gr_code = tgr.[value]
    INNER JOIN #store_codes tsc on d.store_code = tsc.[value]
WHERE h.doc_dt BETWEEN convert(DATETIME, @from_dt, 103)
    AND convert(DATETIME, @to_dt, 103)
    AND sh.Stat_Code <> 'CA'
GROUP BY sh.cmp_id
    , d.unitcode
    , d.store_code
    , st.item_code
    , d.item_code
    , im.item_desc
END
```

Comment: @vikaskumbhar , all the split variable are `VARCHAR(max)` which means there can be more than 50 value in each.So #temp table is preferred than table variable .else reduce variable size to `VARCHAR(50)`

Answer (score 0):

Use [table-valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) instead of CSV strings. Alternatively in your proc
create temp tables (table variables) first.

```
declare @tunitcode table (id int); -- you type may be different
insert @tunitcode(id) 
select * 
from utilfn_split(@unitcode, ',');

.. AND d.unitcode IN (
            SELECT * FROM @tunitcode)
..
```

Comment: As they are splitting different strings each time and not re-using the result of the same split across multiple predicates it isn't clear why this would help. They may be lucky and get better cardinality estimates but if the aim of pre-splitting is to improve this adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` would be better rather than just inserting to table variables and leaving at that

Comment: @MartinSmith Can we be sure `SELECT FROM tvf(@arg)` will always be spooled and reused in an execution plan?

Comment: it doesn't have to be spooled and re-used if the join type is hash or merge as both of those only process each input once. Nor does it have to be spooled if on the outer side of a nested loops. The only time this consideration is relevant is if on the inner side of the nested loops, we haven't seen the execution plan so have no reason to think repeated re-evaluation of the split is causing the OP's problems